# Ruby override .index() in String to search for a character or its HTML equivalent

Tags: html, ruby, overriding

So... I've been working with WYSIWYG editors, and have realized, that they occasionally replace certain characters with the hex codes for that character, like the `'` or the `&` for example.

How do I override String's index method such that it includes these hex codes?

Like, when  do `somestring.index("\'hello there")` how do I get it to search `\'` and `&#39;`

note: single quote is escaped for clarity against double quotes.

what is the most efficient way to do this kind of string search?
is there something like this already built in.

Also, since I'm using external tools, I don't really have a say in the format things are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THE SOLUTION:

```
 search_reg_exp = Regexp.escape(str).gsub(/(both|options|or|more)/, "(both|options|or|more)")

  long_str.index(search_reg_exp)
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

`String#index` doesn't just work for single characters, it can be used for a substring of any length, and you can give it a regular expression which would probably be best in this case:

```
some_string    = "Russell's teapot"
another_string = "Russell&#39;s teapot"

apostrophe_expr = /'|&#39;/

some_string.index apostrophe_expr
# => 7

another_string.index apostrophe_expr
# => 7
```

Another option would be to just decode the HTML entities before you start manipulating the string. There are various gems for this including [html_helpers](https://github.com/tma/html_helpers):

```
require 'html_helpers'

another_string = "Russell&#39;s teapot"

yet_another_string = HTML::EntityCoder.decode_entities another_string
# => "Russell's teapot"

yet_another_string.index "'"
# => 7

yet_another_string.index ?'  # bonus syntax tip--Ruby 1.9.1+
# => 7
```

Comment: your first solution: how do you do that if the search text is either some string or another string, and your searching in a much larger body of text?

Comment: You can use any number of `|` characters in a regular expression to match any of several choices, e.g. `/foo|bar|baz/`. Regular expressions are a big topic but one you'll have to learn eventually. The Pickaxe has [a good very-short intro](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ).

Comment: i know regex, It's more an issue of how do I escape a whole string for regex, so it just tries to match what's there, and doesn't do any other things... just straight up matching. once that is done, I need to gsub the ' or HTML code with the regex equiv of both.

Comment: UPDATE. its Regexp.escape(str).gsub(/(both|options)/, "(both|options)")